# multiple printf not work error 6

Tags: c, cgi

I have a problem with output of my c program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char* valueOfParam (char *param) {
//some code but in this case result is null
    return NULL;
}

int main () {
//....
char *vm_title = valueOfParam("title"); 
unsigned int vm_vc; 
if (valueOfParam("vc"))
vm_vc = atoi(valueOfParam("vc"));           
unsigned int vm_dc; 
if (valueOfParam("dc"))
vm_dc  = atoi(valueOfParam("dc"));
unsigned int vm_cl; 
if (valueOfParam("cl"))
vm_cl = atoi(valueOfParam("cl"));
unsigned int vm_pl; 
if (valueOfParam("pl"))
vm_pl = atoi(valueOfParam("pl"));
//.....
printf("vm_title=%s \n<br>", vm_title);
printf("vm_vc=%d \n<br>", vm_vc);
printf("vm_dc=%d \n<br>", vm_dc);
printf("vm_cl=%d \n<br>", vm_cl);
//.....
}
```

When I try print `1` or `2` value all is good, if I print `2` or more string value I have crash and

```
segfault, error 6 in /var/log/messages.
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Problem was in not this code fragment, sorry.

```
unsigned int vm_users;                              
if (valueOfParam("users")){
    printf("==%s", vm_users);
    //vm_users  = atoi(valueOfParam("users"));
}
```

In particular, in line (crash if uncomment)

```
vm_users  = atoi(valueOfParam("users"));
```

Comment: `printf("vm_title=%s \n<br>", vm_title);` with `wm_title == NULL`, that's fishy$

Comment: valueOfParam("users") return NULL

Comment: don't try to printf NULL...

Comment: printf("==%d \t", atoi(valueOfParam("users")));
Work fine!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP just needs to learn the C a bit. SO is not a teaching portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience.

The problem turned out to be uncertain variables. I simply need to assign them a zero and problem was solved.
I'm surprised that without explicitly specifying any one variable may crash the program when processing other variables.

I will delete this question after some time, as it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("vm_title=%s \n<br>", vm_title);` dereferences the NULL pointer and you are getting the SEGFAULT which is not surprising but expected.

next

`vm_users  = atoi(valueOfParam("users"));` NULL pointer is dereferenced in the atoi function

```
unsigned int vm_users;                              
if (valueOfParam("users")){
    printf("==%s", vm_users);
    //vm_users  = atoi(valueOfParam("users"));
}
```

here you dereference pointer casted from the uninitialised unsigned int variable - another UB.

BTW in 10 lines of code so many UBs. My advise - read a C book first, then code.

Comment: "read a C book first, then code" I convert in "Read C book and program at the same time." Thanks!!

Comment: As you see it does not work. Read try to understand and then code

Comment: I was in despair, as it is not my code, and its more than 14K rows. ((

Comment: If it is coded like this - there is only one choice - the delete button (or rm command)